# How do I select a songnames.id from the songs table in this particular database layout?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select a `songnames.id` from the `songs` table by specifying the `songnames.name` and multiple `artists.name` that are linked to the `songnames.id` in the `songs` table?

```
CREATE TABLE songnames (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    alias VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB' DEFAULT CHARSET = 'UTF8';

CREATE TABLE artists (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB' DEFAULT CHARSET= 'UTF8';

CREATE TABLE songs (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    artist_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES artists(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    songname_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES songnames(id) ON UPDATE     CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE(artist_id, songname_id)
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB' DEFAULT CHARSET = 'UTF8';


songs table:                       artists table:

+----+-----------+-------------+   +----+---------------+
| id | artist_id | songname_id |   | id |     name      |
+----+-----------+-------------+   +----+---------------+
|  1 |     1     |      1      |   | 1  | Matt White    |
+----+-----------+-------------+   +----+---------------+
|  2 |     2     |      2      |   | 2  | Keyshia Cole  |
+----+-----------+-------------+   +----+---------------+
|  3 |     3     |      3      |   | 3  | Nitty Kutchie |
+----+-----------+-------------+   +----+---------------+
|  4 |     4     |      3      |   | 4  | Lukie D       |
+----+-----------+-------------+   +----+---------------+
|  5 |     5     |      4      |   | 5  | Sia           |
+----+-----------+-------------+   +----+---------------+

songnames table:

+----+--------------+--------------+
| id |     name     |     alias    |
+----+--------------+--------------+
| 1  | Love         |         NULL |
+----+--------------+--------------+
| 2  | Love         |         NULL |
+----+--------------+--------------+
| 3  | Love         | Must Be Love |
+----+--------------+--------------+
| 4  | The Greatest |         NULL |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

[This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fde558/6) is what I have played around with so far, I just can't find a way to select a `songname_id` by given `artists.name` and `songnames.name`.

This seems to be working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  songnames.id
FROM songs
JOIN songnames ON songs.songname_id = songnames.id
JOIN artists ON songs.artist_id = artists.id
WHERE songnames.name = 'Love' AND artists.name = 'Matt White'
```

But I need something similiar to (this one obviously fails to execute):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  songnames.id
FROM songs
JOIN songnames ON songs.songname_id = songnames.id
JOIN artists ON songs.artist_id = artists.id
WHERE songnames.name = 'Love' AND artists.name = 'Lukie D' AND artists.name = 'Nitty Kutchie'
```

How do I select the `songnames.id` (id 3) from the `songs` table by specifying a `songnames.name` ('Love') and (multiple) `artists.name` ('Lukie D', 'Nitty Kutchie')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the songs matching the song name and an artist. Then group by the song name and see if you got a match for every artist.

The following query looks up all songs called 'Love', looks for 'Lukie D' and 'Nitty Kutchie', and then only keeps the one 'Love' song that is performed by both (i.e. `count(*) = 2`) artists.

```
select songname_id
from songs
where songname_id in (select id from songnames where name = 'Love')
and artist_id in (select id from artists where name in ('Lukie D', 'Nitty Kutchie'))
group by songname_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fde558/10

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I have trying to figure out!